# How to test project with TestNG alone?

Tags: java, testng

My task is to test an app with TestNG alone, which is ran on a tomcat server. The app is written in JAVA. I have the API endpoints of the app, however how can I test the application using POST and GET methods?

I would like to test e.g: `http://localhost:8080/sportsbetting-web/login` , and I should `POST` the user credentials. How can I test if the login is valid or invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you don't run tests on your server directly.

You can use projects like Wiremock within TestNG (so, no, not with TestNG alone) to replicate/stub any expected (or unexpected) requests and responses, then you need to implement an HTTP Client that communicates with your test server when the tests run.